# Is there a way to do async computations before the app is finished loading?

Tags: react-native

I want to get some data from the localstorage on the device before the first screen starts rendering. I already have the functionality in place, but my question is as follows: 
Is there a way to execute code before React Native shows the first screen?

Right now I have added an extra screen that does these computations, when it is done, it will redirect to the "Home" page. However I would like to eliminate this launch screen altogether.

Right now, I have it implemented like this:

APP LAUNCH -> go to startup screen -> do some async computations -> once finished, go to home page.

The expected result would look something like this.

APP LAUNCH -> do some async computations -> once finished, go to home page.

Comment: are you using react-navigation?

Comment: Yes I am using react-navigation

Comment: please see my answer there are links about switch navigator

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the react-navigation so you can use the switch navigator

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3

Comment: Switch Navigator is the way to go.